# Search API Call Returns Results Outside The Specified ChannelID

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a YT API search query that is limited to a specific channel but returns results outside that channel which is an issue.

Give an through scouring of this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list the following request was done.

https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg&q=%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE&key={your key}

Just to be clear the 'q' parm is Hindi and translates to "तवा"

In the results there are items that are not from the channel specified in the channelId in the request. This seems to be a bug in the YT API.

200

- Show headers -

  `{
   "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/hJ1ihb5XsXgS7tq9QigswU-SsUg\"",
   "regionCode": "US",
   "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
   },
   "items": [
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/9R-AWbPk35j_zGJcL7wemicat9g\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "GfNUaVFmxaY"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2014-05-26T11:16:17.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
      "title": "Introduction to Plumbing Tools (Part-1) (Hindi) (हिन्दी)",
      "description": "This video will help you understand plumbing tools. इस पाठ में आप नल साजी (प्ल्म्बींग) में इस्तेमाल होनेवाल...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GfNUaVFmxaY/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GfNUaVFmxaY/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GfNUaVFmxaY/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "SkillTrain",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/kcnTk-acx88HM9_HoWokq8FRONI\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "swmvPyzi_3c"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2017-12-23T15:00:06.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCH4Bz5Swatl5iHSuCT_Hlxg",
      "title": "पैन: जंगली के महान भगवान - (ग्रीक पौराणिक कथाओं में बताया)",
      "description": "आज हम कम देवताओं में से एक है और मेरे पसंदीदा में से एक पर एक नज़र डालें, जंगली के परमेश्वर पैन। आप पौराणिक कथाओं और लोक-साहित्य का आनंद लें और अधिक जानने के लिए चाहते हैं।",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/swmvPyzi_3c/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/swmvPyzi_3c/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/swmvPyzi_3c/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Mythology & Fiction Explained",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/qE49UjY2s7xfzQc3lgM2V2089Cs\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "tjW1mKwNUSo"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2014-11-25T17:00:03.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCjmJDM5pRKbUlVIzDYYWb6g",
      "title": "पान - आधिकारिक टीज़र ट्रेलर [HD]",
      "description": "ह्यूग जैकमैन, गैरेट Hedlund, रूनी मारा और पैन में लेवी मिलर स्टार, थिएटर में 9 वीं अक्टूबर! http://www.pan-movie.com/ ...",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tjW1mKwNUSo/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tjW1mKwNUSo/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tjW1mKwNUSo/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Warner Bros. Pictures",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    },
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
     "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/-zDpouVDxXZOX5hD6tlEcP9BeEM\"",
     "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "vjGM6eLR5ZE"
     },
     "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2017-12-10T05:52:59.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCOvw0-6WFFEMr__v4mFonxQ",
      "title": "गोकू खो पान | अंग्रेजी डब",
      "description": "जबकि गोकू, पिकोलो, और Chichi उसे खोजने की कोशिश पान पुलाव के साथ एक साहसिक है। #ड्रेगन बॉल सुपर।",
      "thumbnails": {
       "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vjGM6eLR5ZE/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
       },
       "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vjGM6eLR5ZE/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
       },
       "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vjGM6eLR5ZE/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
       }
      },
      "channelTitle": "GOT-two",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
     }
    }
   ]
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure whether it is a bug or not, but, you're getting results from different channels due to the `q` parameter and its value - that's the intended functionality.

The `q` parameter search also in the **`description of the video`**.

So, if you want exclude results from other channels in your request you can do this:

- If you really need add a search term, add it and add the name of your channel.

Example:

> q=तवा + SkillTrain

You can test this request in this [demo at Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg&q=%25E0%25A4%25A4%25E0%25A4%25B5%25E0%25A4%25BE+%252B+SkillTrain&fields=items(id(channelId%252Ckind%252CvideoId)%252Ckind%252Csnippet(channelId%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=10&).

And these are the results:

```
{
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "GfNUaVFmxaY"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
    "title": "Introduction to Plumbing Tools (Part-1) (Hindi) (हिन्दी)"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

In this case, there is one result that matched with both, your channel_id and the supplied Hindi character.

or

- If you don't need add a search parameter, omit it from your request and *(since you had added the `channel_id` value)*, once made the request, you'll get the following results:

---

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 666,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "td3GPjcXPb4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
    "title": "Basic components of a window AC (Hindi) (हिन्दी)"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "e611N5gR1z4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
    "title": "Wheel balancing (Hindi) (हिन्दी)"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "XCitxJ-jvgQ"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
    "title": "Auto Clave (Hindi) (हिन्दी)"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "8zHSEv_tziQ"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
    "title": "Understanding the components of a split AC (Hindi) (हिन्दी)"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "WQ8X3hDIwJM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg",
    "title": "Brake pad replacement (Hindi)(हिन्दी)"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

All these results are from the provided `channel_id`.

You can test this request in this [demo at Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCoMurV7497Rj7kk5i-UXUhg&fields=items(id(channelId%252Ckind%252CvideoId)%252Ckind%252Csnippet(channelId%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=11&).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I find it strange that what you have done works and I don't remember seeing anything about adding the channel name within the 'q' parameter value to do this. Can you point me to that or how you figured this out?

Comment: @Jeff, I figured this out by intuition and "trial and error" *(no documentation or anything related)*. If my answer solved your problem, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that! Did it work for other channels and query strings? I want to accept your answer but I'm still a little skeptical that it was tested enough. What we ended up doing is actually sorting the results ourselves since we know what channel we are querying and the channel info is included in each result item.

Comment: @Jeff. I understand, if you can provide me some channel_ids you have in mind *(and the scenarios/`q` value)*, I can test it and share my results. With the modifications you made in your channel, now you wont have results from other channels *(I know this because I clicked both, the URL request you provided in your question and the demos I prepared for you in my answer)*.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio! Very generous of you! I'll get some folks to take this on internally. I'm sure you have other things you'd prefer to be doing. :-)